# Redis Cache not working with Asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, redis

I try to implement redis cache in Asp.Net Core Application but its not Set any value in HttpContext.Session and not even return any value.This is my startup.cs  file.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
        {
            options.InstanceName = Configuration.GetValue<string>("redis:name");
            options.Configuration = Configuration.GetValue<string>("redis:host");
        });
        services.AddSession(o=> { o.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5); });  
        services.AddMvc();
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseStaticFiles();


        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Appsetting.json

```
 "redis": {
"host": "redis-17930.c1.ap-southeast-1-1.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com",
"port": 17930,
"name": "Astroyogi"
  },
```

HomeController.cs

```
   public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var helloRedis = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello Redis");
        HttpContext.Session.Set("hellokey", helloRedis);

        var getHello = default(byte[]);
        HttpContext.Session.TryGetValue("hellokey", out getHello);
        ViewData["Hello"] = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(getHello);

       return View();
    }
```

and the lib which i installed-
Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session

and its will not set any value in session.
Please help me where i am stucking.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot both set and get the value you just set in the `Session` in the same request. Session requires a cookie to be set, which will only happen after you return the response. On the next request, you should be able to access your value fine.